# Redirecting and rewriting in NGINX

Tags: redirect, nginx, webserver, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a simple "Hello World"-like API and for that I need a rule to redirect/rewrite the URL to my API.

Let's say my file is called `index.php`, so whenever I make a `GET` to `index.php` I get a list of `items`.

The first thing I want to do is to redirect the URL `mydomain.com/index.php` to `mydomain.com/api`.

And second, when `mydomain.com/api` is accessed, I'd like the server to trigger the `index.php` file without rewriting the URL.

My current code looks like this:

```
location /api {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/index.php permanent;
}

location /index.php{
    return 302 www.mydomain.com/api;
}
```

but it's not working as expected. Why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two rules for what you're trying to achieve.

The first one, the one that will receive requests and "translate" them to your under-the-hood script, should look like this:

```
rewrite ^/api\?(.+)$ /index.php?$1 last;
```

As for the second one, the one that should redirect all your users to the "beautiful" URL:

```
rewrite  ^/index.php\?(.*)$    /api?$1    permanent;
```

Note that this second rule should be **outside** any location block and **before** any of those, as you're willing to redirect the user **before** anything else.

Cheers

Comment: There is a problem with the conditional and the capturing group. The ? should go after the capturing group: rewrite ^/api(.+)?$ /index.php?$1 last;   rewrite  ^/index.php(.*)?$    /api?$1    permanent;

Comment: @alfredocambera No, in fact it should go before the group as it's matching the literal character ```?```, rather than making whatever comes after ```index.php``` optional.

Comment: @alexandernst you are contionally matching 'i' on your first expression, and the 'p' on your second expression. Check http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=^%2Fapi%28.%2B%29%3F%24 and http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=^%2Fapi%3F%28.%2B%29%24

Comment: @alfredocambera Ah, indeed. SO wiped the escape character while parsing my answer. Will edit right now

Comment: @alexandernst I would suggest you to test your expression on http://regex101.com/#PCRE . Try api\?(.+)$ and api(.+)?$

Comment: @alfredocambera Why ```api\?(.+)?$``` ?  I answered with ```api\?(.+)$``` which returns exactly the same thing as your regex.

Comment: Fixed. I made a mistake. Please, try again with the updated version :D

Comment: @alfredocambera well... Can't really say what do you want me to test. The test data is ```www.domain.com/api?arg1=foo&arg2=bar```. Applying my regex (```api\?(.+)$```) returns only the args. Applying your edit (```api(.+)?$```) returns the args, prepended with an ```?```.

Answer (score 0):

```
# you don't need a rewrite. Use location with the "=" or exact match
location = /api {
    alias /path/to/root;
    index index.php;
}

location /index.php {
    return 302 www.mydomain.com/api;
}
```

Hope it helps

**Here is the second version of my answer using one redirect and an alias:**

```
   location /api {                                
     alias /path/to/root;                       
     index index.php;                             
   }                                              

   # replace index.php with api                   
   location /index.php {                          
     rewrite (index\.php)(.*)$ /api$2 permanent;  
   }
```

My first solution did not forwarded the args. Reading @alexandernst solution gave a better idea of the problem.

Comment: So, if  i wanna access /index.php writting /api, i have to use :
location = /api{
            alias /;
            index index.php;
        }

it dosent work .. it goes to /api/ and give me a 404 (maybe searching /api/index.php? )

Comment: What do u see on your access logs? which path is it looking for on your filesystem?

Comment: When i access to **www.mydomain.com/api** chrome network log says me that www.mydomain.com/api **moved permanently (301)** to www.mydomain.com/api/ and throws **404 error** after that.

Comment: It means there is no index.php on that directory. If you try www.mydomain.com/api/index.php it should show the same message. The access logs show the filesystem path, its trying to access.

Comment: Whats the content of your "root" directory? Whats the content of your "api" directory?

Comment: My **api** directory dosent exist, i want to access to **index.php** in the root directory, writting in the url **/api** , and viceversa (writting **index.php**, rewrite the url to **/api**, but stay in index.php)

Comment: Yep, thats what i said in my first comment, the alias is **alias /** and it dosent working as expected.

Comment: Please post your access log corresponding to the failing requests